# Listview items and saving them as .csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I'm doing this project where I need to save the names of the items from a listview to a .csv

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class cv7import

Private Sub cv7import_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim caminho As String
    caminho = "C:\Documents and Settings\Software\Ambiente de trabalho\cv7import"

    Dim returnValue As String()
    returnValue = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If returnValue.Length > 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(returnValue(1).ToString())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing")
    End If

    ' Set ListView Properties  
    lstvicon.View = View.Details
    lstvicon.GridLines = False
    lstvicon.FullRowSelect = True
    lstvicon.HideSelection = False
    lstvicon.MultiSelect = True

    ' Create Columns Headers  
    lstvicon.Columns.Add("Nome")
    lstvicon.Columns.Add("Extensão")
    lstvicon.Columns.Add("Tamanho")
    lstvicon.Columns.Add("Data Modificação")

    Dim DI As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(caminho)

    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo = DI.GetFiles

    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo

    Dim li As ListViewItem
    For Each file In files
        li = lstvicon.Items.Add(file.Name)
        li.SubItems.Add(file.Extension)
        li.SubItems.Add(file.Length)
        li.SubItems.Add(file.LastWriteTimeUtc)
        'li.SubItems.Add(FileDialog)
    Next



End Sub

Private Sub btnimp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnimp.Click

    ' Creates a csv File
    Dim csv As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Documents and Settings\Software\Ambiente de trabalho\cv7import\teste.csv", True)

    lstvicon.SelectedItems.CopyTo(csv)

    csv.Close()


End Sub
End Class
```

That's what I got but I can't seem to get it to write on the .txt.

I have no idea where to go from here and i've been going around this for hours, so any help would be apreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4kyezf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this:

```
    ' Creates a csv File
    Using csv As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Documents and Settings\Software\Ambiente de trabalho\cv7import\teste.csv", True)
        For Each oItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            csv.WriteLine(String.Format("""{0}"",""{1}"",{2},{3}", oItem.Text, oItem.SubItems(0).Text, oItem.SubItems(1).Text, oItem.SubItems(2).Text )
        Next
    End Using
```

You will probably need to clean up the csv formatting, but this should give you an idea.